# Asterisk как отправить данные звонка, перед и после звонка

Tags: asterisk, телефония

Нашел такой код, для отправки данных о звонке. Но как я понял это для отправке завершенных звонков (h). Я в него уже дописал вызов curl для отправки звонков.

```
[ext-queues]
exten => h,1,System(/usr/bin/curl -d "CALLERID=${CALLERID(num)}" -d "DIALSTATUS=${DIALSTATUS}" -d "NODEST=${NODEST}" -d "EPOCH=${EPOCH}" -d "EXTEN=${EXTEN}" -d "ext=end" --max-time 5 --insecure https://server/page/ & )
exten => h,2,Macro(hangupcall,)
```

Подскажите, как можно отправить данные о звонке. 1й раз когда начали разговор с оператором и 2й раз по завершению звонка. Я так понимаю это надо писать там. где начинается звонок? искать место где используется модификатор (s)?